# Cross multiplication in c#

Tags: c#

I've two scenarios where I have to find result based on parameters(by doing cross multiplication). Those scenarios are as following:

For example,

Scenario - 1:

```
int previousConceptCount = 100
int currentConceptCount = 20
int previousTime = 10
int currentTime = ?

Que: If 100 concepts take 10 mins to complete than how much time 20 concepts will take?
Ans: 
currentTime = (currentConceptCount * previousTime) / previousConceptCount //Works fine

//Mathematical calculation which I've added in code.  
  100     10
 ----- = -----  ==> x = (20(currentConceptCount) * 10(previousTime)) / 100(previousConceptCount)
  20       x
```

Scenario - 2:

```
int previousConceptCount = 10
int currentConceptCount = 100
int previousDocumentCount = 100
int currentDocumentCount = 100
int previousTime = 10
int currentTime = ?

    Que: If 10 concepts with 100 documents take 10 mins than how much time 100 concepts with 100 documents will take?
Ans: 
    currentTime = ?
```

How to calculate `currentTime` in this kind of scenario. I'll always have `conceptCounts(both previous and current)` and `documentCounts(both previous and current)` and based on that I've to find time.  I don't know what math formula will be needed or let me put it this way, I do not know how to calculate in this scenario.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does each concept use 100 documents or does the group of concepts use all 100 documents?

Comment: @druidicwyrm group of concepts

Comment: Do the amount documents affect the time or not? Like for you question does it matter that it takes an average of 10 docs per concept for the previous counts whereas it takes 1 doc per concept on your current counts?

Comment: @druidicwyrm amount of doc count affects the time. That is the main factor. For Example, for 100 documents 10 concepts could take less time compare to 20 concepts. All the concepts will go through the documents.

Comment: 10 concepts with 100 docs = 10 mins so 100 concepts that each have 100 docs will be 10 times longer (100 / 10) so the answer is 1hr 40mins (100mins) OR 10 concepts with 100 docs = 10mins... so 1 concept with 100 docs = 10mins / 10 (concepts) = 1min... so 100 concepts each with 100docs = 100 (concepts with 100docs) x 1min = 100mins or 1hr 40mins

Answer (score 0):

You just need to multiply your concepts by your documents:

```
(20(currentConceptCount*currentDocumentCount) * 10(previousTime)) / 100(previousConceptCount*previousDocumentCount)
```

Comment: I can try this formula.  Thanks for suggestion.